# Scrapy error: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I made a scraper and am using [this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html) tutorial to export using a pipeline. When I run `scrapy crawl [myspider]` I see the objects flashing by in my terminal, but after each it gives the error  `'PostPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'`.

**My Spider**

```
class FokSpider1(CrawlSpider):
name = 'fok'
allowed_domains = ['fok.nl']
start_urls = ['http://forum.fok.nl/?token=77c1f767bc31859fee1ffe041343fa48&allowcookies=ACCEPTEER+ALLE+COOKIES']

rules = (
    # My rules, leave out to save space
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    super(FokSpider1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def parse_topic(self, response):
    posts = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'post userid')]")

    for i, post in enumerate(posts):
        l = ItemLoader(selector=post, item=ForumTopic(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('subforum_title',"//*[@id='pageWrapper']/div[4]/div/h2/a/text()")
        l.add_xpath('topic_title',"//*[@id='pageWrapper']/div[4]/h1/span/text()")
        l.add_xpath('unique_post_id', ".//@data-postid")
        l.add_xpath('post_rank', ".//@data-teller")
        l.add_xpath('author', ".//@data-member")
        l.add_xpath('timestamp', ".//span[contains(@class, 'post_time')]/a[1]/text()")
        l.add_xpath('content', ".//div[contains(@id, '_bot')]/div[contains(@class, 'postmain_right')]/text()")
        yield l.load_item()
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy_spider.pipelines.PostPipeline': 300,
}
```

I don't think the rest of settings.py is relevant?

**pipelines.py**

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import XmlItemExporter


class PostPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('fokSpider1.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['unique_post_id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['unique_post_id'])
            self.exporter.export_item(item)
            return item
```

**Additional info**

The error is raised at the `process_item` method:

```
    2017-12-18 17:24:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'author': u'HaverMoutKoekje',
 'content': u'Here is the content',
 'post_rank': u'7',
 'subforum_title': u'televisie',
 'timestamp': u'vrijdag 8 december 2017 @ 21:59',
 'unique_post_id': u'175586521'}
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/my.name/scrapy/scrapy_spider/scrapy_spider/pipelines.py", line 40, in process_item
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
AttributeError: 'PostPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'**
```

When I run `scrapy crawl [myspider] -o somefile.xml`, the file is created, but it has no content.

Same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807649/attributeerror-newscrawlerpipeline-object-has-no-attribute-exporter-scrap), but no answers over there...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
While not really solving this problem, I for now can at least export data using the simple pipeline

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class PostPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
        self.files = {}

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['unique_post_id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['unique_post_id'])
            return item
```

using the command `scrapy crawl [myspider] -o somefile.xml`. Why the earlier approach, taken straight from the tutorials, did not work, still no idea.

Comment: Maybe I am just missing it, but where do you call the `spider_opened` function?

Comment: See my section pipelines.py, it's between `from_crawler` and `spider_closed`.

Comment: Not where it is defined, where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

`file = open('fokSpider1.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')`

This doesn't look right. But why it is not raising error?

anyway, maybe this is the cause, your exporter param is incorrect, so it is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

the init fun. will make a difference in the whole map, you can try like this:

```py
class PostPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()
        self.file = open('fokSpider1.xml', 'w+b')
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(self.file)
```